# Keep URL encoding after .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Suppose my domain is `foo.com`. If I open `http://foo.com/something`, it will be redirected to `http://www.foo.com/something`. This works nicely, except when `something` contains any [url encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) characters.

If I open `http://www.foo.com/bar/file-with-%3F-in-name`, the `REQUEST_URI` is `/bar/file-with-%3F-in-name`.

If I open `http://foo.com/bar/file-with-%3F-in-name`, however, the url encoded `%3F` is decoded to `?` during rewrite, and the `REQUEST_URI` becomes `/bar/file-with-` with the `QUERY_STRING` `-in-name`.

How can I keep the url encoded characters from being decoded during rewrite?

I've tried using the [B](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) and [NE](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) flags, but without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is version of rule that will solve your problem:

```
# Rewrite www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S*)\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

- Trick is to grab the request URI from `THE_REQUEST` variable before it gets decoded by Apache.
- `NE` is still needed to avoid `%3F` becoming `%253F`

It was my mistake earlier that I didn't interpret question correctly.